# Overlay UIView who detect touches, process them and send them to underneath view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, overlay

I've created a view which should handle all the touches, swipes... etc. This view will be always on top off all the others views and will cover the device screen. What I want is this view to get all the events, process them in a transparent way.

I've tried using:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSSet *tmpTouches = [event allTouches];

    if (tmpTouches.count == 1)
        NSLog(@"1 tap detected");
    else if (tmpTouches.count == 2)
        NSLog(@"w tap detected");
    else if (tmpTouches.count == 3)
        NSLog(@"3 tap detected");

    UIView *hitTestView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitTestView) {
        hitTestView = nil;
    }
    return hitTestView;
}
```

but no touch are detected in Events

---

On the next method if return `YES` I can use `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` ... etc but how to send the touch event to the next view. If return `NO` the view is transparent for the system but I don't get any touches..

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{   
    return NO;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: add gesture recognizer to the view

Comment: Isn't this `if (hitTestView) {
    hitTestView = nil;
}
return hitTestView;` just a long way of saying `return nil;`?

Comment: Yes you right ... it should be: UIView *hitTestView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitTestView)
        return hitTestView;
    return nil;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a reference to your sub view in your main view. Use the touchesBegan, etc. mechanism to grab your touches.  In your main view, directly call the method in your subview that should handle thate event.  In other words, the main view absorbs the event, then calls the appropriate method in the subview.  This will be easier than trying to divvy up the events between the two views.

Comment: I was thinking about this solution but is a pain in the ass to add tap detection in each view... I would liked to have only one class (UIView) to handle all the user interaction ... and to update the state depending on the active view...

Comment: @Kyll. I cannot edit it anymore and I don't wanna comment your comment ...

Comment: I'm saying you only detect user touches in your main view, just call routines in your subviews that need to update the state. You don't need to pass the touches down, just call the routines in the subview that will be affected by that touch.

Comment: I see what you say but is complicate to do that. Is not a simple project and will have multiple scroll views in scroll views. I was thinking to do something else: Have a base class where I could put all the touches/gestures... etc. From this class I will call another one which will do what is needed. From this class I will create (children's) all the viewControllers... so this way each view will have all types of detection and I will need to work only in one NSObject class... need to test that Idea... I will come with a feedback if works smoothly or not..

Comment: I've tried the system that I explained in a previous comment and it works perfect. I will chose your answer because It was the closest one... Ty for help!